# How to get VS Code to change font weight of italics?

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

Currently using a [font](https://github.com/kosimst/Firicico) with italics. Unfortunately the italics are a bit too difficult to read, and I suspect changing the font weight to make them a bit less bold will do the trick. Any ideas how to do this? (included is settings and a screenshot)

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": [
          //following will be in italics (=Pacifico)
          "comment",
          "entity.name.type.class", //class names
          "keyword", //import, export, return…
          //"support.class.builtin.js", //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
          "storage.modifier", //static keyword
          "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
          "storage.type.function.js", // function keyword
          "storage.type.js", // Variable declarations
          "keyword.control.import.js", // Imports
          "keyword.control.from.js", // From-Keyword
          //"entity.name.type.js", // new … Expression
          "keyword.control.flow.js", // await
          "keyword.control.conditional.js", // if
          "keyword.control.loop.js", // for
          "keyword.operator.new.js", // new
        ],
        "settings": {
          "fontStyle": "italic",
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "HTML Attributes",
        "scope": [
          "text.html.basic entity.other.attribute-name.html",
          "text.html.basic entity.other.attribute-name"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "fontStyle": "italic",
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": [
          //following will be excluded from italics (My theme (Monokai dark) has some defaults I don't want to be in italics)
          "invalid",
          "keyword.operator",
          "constant.numeric.css",
          "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
          "constant.numeric.decimal.js",
          "constant.numeric.json",
          "entity.name.type.class.js"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "fontStyle": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I second this. I had to remove the extralight-italic fonts front my computer so that VS Code only recognizes the normal-italic ones. Would be great if VS Code gives a way to customize this easily.

Comment: Anybody find a way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

this pc > local disc > Users > pc > .vscode > extensions > (your extention that changes your texmate scopes) > themes > (.JSON file right click and edit in a text editor (like notepad or vscode itself))
here is how one might look like:

```html
    {
      "name": "Comment",
      "scope": [
        "comment",
        "string.comment"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#3b6b5d",
        "fontStyle": "italic"
      }
    },
```

Here you can edit the fontStyle to the one that you desire (example: `"italic"`, `"bold"`, `"underline"`, `"italic bold underline"`).
If you are looking to change the font weight of "bold" text in editor then it's not possible.

Answer (score -2):

You have to change user settings as per below

1. File > Preferences > Settings
2. Choose User Setting
3. Choose Text Editor > Font

If you are using JSON then add below settings:

`"editor.fontWeight": "normal",`

`"editor.fontSize": 14,`

`"editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace"'`

Currently, I am using v1.30.1

Comment: Won't that change the font settings for all types? I am aiming to modify only italics

Comment: Please read the question before answering, this answer changes fonts globally for VS Code, which is not what is being asked.